# Cannot call Authenticated API Gateway lambda endpoint via API Gateway Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Currently, I have a AWS API Gateway REST API that has lambda endpoints secured with AWS_IAM authentication. Currently, my client is calling this endpoint successfully and getting back valid responses.

I am now trying to introduce a proxy API Gateway in front of this REST API and update the client to call the endpoint via this proxy. For unauthenticated endpoints on my REST API the proxy is working fine but for the endpoints secured with AWS_IAM I am getting a 403 error and a response

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

The request to the proxy or direct to the REST API is identical other than the url called. Is anyone able to explain why this would be the case and how I might go about resolving it?

Comment: Double check this: "The request to the proxy or direct to the REST API is identical"

Comment: @Luca I have tested in Postman changing only the url